# How does a be_valid matcher know something is actually valid

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am reading RSpec and in the first examples I see something like this:

```
Class Foo  # in the model

attr_accessible :name, :phone , etc#....

validates :name, presence: true
validates :phone, presence: true
```

Then in the RSpec I see like

```
it "is valid with a name" do
  foo = Foo.new (name: "blah")
  expect(foo).to be_valid
end
```

So I guess my confusion is what is this be_valid doing? how does it know name is valid?
Does be_valid mean go and check if we have defined validators for our model, go and see what are does?  in this case we said name should be present, so now that we have passed the name, it means it is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`be_*` matcher is one of rspec's tricks. When you say

```
foo.should be_valid
```

rspec will go call `valid?` method on `foo` and check for its return value. `valid?` method (defined in your ORM), in turn, will invoke your validators.

In short, `be_valid` doesn't know anything about validators. It's a general mechanism.

Comment: but I don't have a "valid?" method defined by me in the model

Comment: hmm..Ok.  So that "valid?" method its self, does it go and look at the "validates" statements that I have written in the model?

Comment: You could say that, yes. `valid?` method triggers validation checks.

Comment: one last question: so if I define a method like "good_enough?" in my model, then in RSpec I can have a "be_good_enough"  ?  That's powerful.

Comment: Yep, exactly, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, foo.should be_valid is just calling foo.valid?.
Since the Foo model inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, and ActiveRecord::Base includes its ActiveRecord::Validations module, which in turn includes the module ActiveModel::Validations on itself ( where the valid? method is defined ), your Foo class instantly gains access to this method as well.

You can find info on the valid? method here: [api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F)